# How to open popup in spring mvc application

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, popup

I have following web application structure:

[image]

inside `addTerminal.jsp` I write following:

```
....
<a href="#" class="open-map" onclick="showMap(55,22)">show map</a>
...
function showMap(lat,lng) {
        window.open('map.html?lat='+lat+'&lng='+lng, 'map', 'width=600,height=400');
    }
....
```

But as client cannot access to WEB-INF folder I see 404 when click on `href`

Can you advice workaround how resolve my issue?

I think I can put map.html into webapp folder but I think exist another fix.
Application technology stack:

`Tomcat` + `Hibernate` + `SpringMVC`

web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

     <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
   </listener>

     <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/webContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param> 
    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/webContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>  
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>  
            <param-value>true</param-value>  
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>  
        <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>  
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: You need to add an accessible path to the popup. Placing it in the web-inf would make in inaccessible. Place it in the webapp directory and make sure all requests are not being forwarded to the spring dispatcher servlet but rather that .html is not handled by the dispatcher. Alternatively add a mvc:resource to the .html file then you can leave it in web-inf.

Comment: Can you please post your web config? web.xml or java class depending which version you are using. Also can you post you spring dispatcher xml config or javaconfig? That way I can give you a answer for your usecase.

Comment: @Kevin Bayes topic updated

Comment: Sorry just say that you are passing query parameters in. Are you doing some processing or just considering this as a html resource that needs to be loaded?

Comment: @Kevin Bayes I pass map coordinates. javascript inside map.html will parse get parameters and draw map.

Comment: Great then the below should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to create a controller that handles requests to `map.html`.

Something similar:

```
@RequestMapping("/map.html")
public String popup(@RequestParam("lat") String lat, @RequestParam("lng") String lng){
    // your code here...
    return "map";
}
```

Comment: This may not work. Depending on the view resolver used this may never send the html file. May look for map.jsp which does not exist in the root of web-inf. Also note that he is using javascript for the parameters. So no need to process the parameters.

Comment: @gstackoverflow Well... your `map.html` is a page like all others, so why don't you want to handle it like any other? IMO showing it in a popup or in the main window is just a detail...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mvc:resources tag to load items you consider resources.

```
<mvc:resources location="/web-inf/<path to html file>" mapping="<url context in a browser>" cache-period="86400"/>
```

Reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-static-resources

Comment: What should I write inside **<url context in a browser>** ?

Comment: If you need the resources to be available at /app/maps/map.html then that should go there. And location should have /WEB-INF/pages/member/createCompany/map.html.

Comment: I will test it in the evening(for 8 hours)

Comment: I tryed to add **<mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/pages/member/createCompany/map.html" mapping="/map.html" />** and **<mvc:resources mapping="/WEB-INF/pages/member/createCompany/map.html" location="/map.html" />** - both doesn't work - 404

Comment: But I have line INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/WEB-INF/pages/member/createCompany/map.html] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#1'

Comment: It works if I writes:        ** window.open('/terminal-company/map.html?lat='+lat+'&lng='+lng, 'map', 'width=600,height=400');** But it is bad idea

Comment: In your original change to window.open("/map.html".... because in mapping="/map.html" but to make it also prepend the context of your application you need to use something like <c:url value="/map.html"></c:url>.

Comment: and it doesn't work for me. it ignores application name

Comment: So your application name is terminal-company right? That is the context for the war file in your container? If so consider not placing direct urls but rather using jstl c:url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63851/discussion-between-kevin-bayes-and-gstackoverflow).

Comment: I have used this tag!

Comment: Can you please then post more information. Like the full addTerminal.jsp and your spring config?